# Wordpress. How to use media library for choosing image in extrafields or media box

Tags: wordpress

I have spent 3 hours, so maybe someone needs the solution. So I answered the question on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo media_buttons(); ?>

<input id="category_image" type="hidden" size="100" name="category_meta[category_image]" value="" />
<div id="category_image_preview"></div>

<script>
(function( $ ) {

    window.send_to_editor = function ( imgHtml ) {

    $( '#category_image_preview' ).html( imgHtml )
        var imgUrl = $( 'img', imgHtml ).attr( 'src' );
        $( '#category_image' ).val( imgUrl );

        tb_remove();
    };

})( jQuery );
</script>
```

[image: The result]